# Combo box issue in Linux KDE environment

Tags: linux, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, kde-plasma

I have a RCP application which works well in Linux GNOME environment.But when I tried the Application with Linux KDE environment 
I am facing some issues with the  combo box.

1.Combo box is not disposing properly.
Also when I tried to debug with eclipse,The entire UI goes to freeze state and I forced to restart my machine.
Is there any library need to be  replaced while using Linux KDE environment?.Also combo box is not behaving as expected using the same code.
Please help me to resolve the issues.

Comment: Which Linux distrobution? Which KDE version? Which Eclipse version?

Comment: Show us the code for the Combo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same issue on Ubuntu. I'm using IBM's Nebula implementation of a TableCombo with slight modifications. If you too, then the following code might help you:

```
getShell().addShellListener(new ShellAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void shellDeactivated(ShellEvent e) {
        Display.getCurrent().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (Display.getCurrent().getFocusControl() == null) {
                    dropDown(false);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Insert this at the end of the createPopup() method.

Comment: I am using SWT combo box in my application.Also what is the dropDown() method in the code.Combo is working properly in the GNome environment.But in KDE it is not working.

Comment: The dropDown() method is part of the TableCombo. See [Nebula TableCombo Widget](https://eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/tablecombo/tablecombo.php) You can find it's java code in several repos. Give it a try with KDE.